# DataGridView column editor empties string properties of a custom column

Tags: .net, visual-studio, datagridview

I've implemented a custom lookup column, but I'm encountering the damnedest thing with the VS designer. The column has four string properties in addition to the standard column props. Now, if I select the column from the component list in the property grid, then set the properties, everything seems to work fine. However, the moment I open up the "edit columns" designer view for the DataGridView, the string properties are emptied.

While a workaround is to not use the column editor, I'm bound to do that at some point, and then wonder what the heck happened to my data. So, what might I be doing so wrong as to cause this?

Edit: Correction: the properties get emptied even if I don't use the DataGridView column editor. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days, it seems every SO question I post is based on a false assumption. This time, the culprit was neither my code nor the designer, but an extender control on the same form.